# Webmin can't start bind9: 'Unknown error'

Tags: dns, bind, webmin

- Ubuntu version: 14.04.1 LTS x86_64
- Bind version: 9.9.5
- Webmin version: 1.780

For a while now, I'm trying to configure bind.
First one as a slave to our current Windows DNS Servers which all works fine, but there is an additional requirement: an Interface.
So I installed Webmin, which came with the bind-module preinstalled and everything works fine, except for restarting the Server. I can stop it, but I cannot start it again. I get an `Failed to start BIND : Unknown error` using the Webmin-Interface. Using `sudo service bind9 start` works perfectly.

---

> **TL;DR:** Bind works perfectly, but I can't start the bind service through the Webmin-Interface

The Syslog sais:

```
Jan 11 14:28:18 SRVNT151 named[20133]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Jan 11 14:28:18 SRVNT151 named[20133]: /etc/bind/named.conf.local:34: open: /etc/bind/rndc.key: permission denied
Jan 11 14:28:18 SRVNT151 named[20133]: loading configuration: permission denied
Jan 11 14:28:18 SRVNT151 named[20133]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

So my guess is, that it for some reason tries to start bind from another user, because the bind user has access to all the files it complains not having access to.

```
-rw-r----- 1 bind bind    76 Jan 11 13:52 rndc.key
```

Note: when I commented out the line including the rndc-file, it complained about not having access to `/var/log/named/named`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  7252744 Jan 11 13:53 named
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an old thread but I ran into the same issue today and I believe the solution. Edit the webmin module config for the Bind DNS settings 
User to start BIND as from default to bind
Group to start BIND as from default to bind

If not you can always start or stop the service in the Boot Up and Shutdown Actions in webmin.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have faced an error like this in Webmin on my Kali VM machine.

```
Failed to start BIND: Failed to start bind9.service: Unit bind9.service not found.
```

In my machine bind9 service can be run from the terminal, but Webmin cannot start it. I figured out it looks for a file "bind9.service" where bind9 calls the file **named.service**, so I made a copy of that and renamed it to bind9.service, and it ran properly. the commands I used are as follows,

```
sudo find / -name named.service
```

from the output I copied this location "/usr/lib/systemd/system"
after that

```
sudo cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
sudo cp named.service bind9.service
```